# How to get Stored cookie value in form of string?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

This is my demo.jsp page where i'm entering data in text box and setting that value in cookies but i dont know how to retrieve the stored data from that.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>
        function validate(){
            var input=document.getElementById("txtBX").value;
            //alert(input);
            setCookie("cookiedata", input);
        }
        function getCookie(name) {
            var start = document.cookie.indexOf( name + "=" );
            var len = start + name.length + 1;
            if ( ( !start ) && ( name != document.cookie.substring( 0, name.length ) ) ) {
                return null;
            }
            if ( start == -1 ) return null;
            var end = document.cookie.indexOf( ";", len );
            if ( end == -1 ) end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape( document.cookie.substring( len, end ) );
        }
        function setCookie(name, value) {               
            var now = new Date();
            var time = now.getTime();
            time += 3600 * 1000;
            now.setTime(time);                             
            document.cookie = name+"=" + value + '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() + ';domain='+window.location.hostname+';path=/';
        }                       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.println("<table><tr><td>");
        out.println("<input type='text' id='txtBX'>");
        out.println("<input type='button' value='go'onclick='validate()'>");
    %>
</body>
```

this is my complete jsp page where i'm setting cookies ,could anybody guide me how to get those cookies as a string.

Comment: document.cookie; give array of all cookies stored and you can get all values by loop and if values are not string than can convert into string by string() function

Comment: <%
            out.println("<table><tr><td>");
            out.println("<input type='text' id='txtbox'>");
            out.println("<input type='button' value='go'onclick='getData()'>");
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            String textValue = "";
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if ("TextDetails".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    textValue = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
            out.println("<tr><td>Entered Data is:" + "" + textValue + "</td></tr>");
            out.println("</td></tr></table>");
%>